# utf-8 filename are ruined when uploading through IIS

Tags: file-upload, utf-8, character-encoding, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

When I upload files with UFT-8 file name through IIS on my Windows Server file names are ruined. (They are changed as if they are encoded in ASCII and therefore they are no more accessible). I Wonder if there is any work around for this problem. I should also mention that my Windows Server doesn't have any issue with UTF-8 file names and I can create them through RDP or FTP. The problem only occurs when uploading through IIS.

> Configuration:
>   OS: Windows Server 2008 SP1
>   Web Server: IIS 7.5
>   Uploading by PHP script executed through fastcgi

Comment: Windows filesystems do not support UTF-8 filenames. The FTP protocol supports UTF-8 but the FTP server has to convert such filenames to Ansi or UTF-16 before passing them to filesystem APIs. A web server has to do the same thing, and so it has to know the filenames are UTF-8 encoded. Chances are, your web client is NOT telling IIS that the filenames are UTF-8 when uploading. That would account for your conversion problem.

Comment: If the PHP script is responsible for handling the file names, the problem may be there.  I have no idea whether PHP on Windows even supports Unicode filenames, most applications ported from UNIX to Windows don't.

Comment: The problem seems to be rooted in PHP. PHP script can't create a file with utf-8 file name. Now I am using a workaround which eliminates non-ASCII characters from file names and to some extent it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is the IIS. The IIS converts all request data to ascii before sending them to the PHP process. Because of this conversion all special characters of the utf-8 encoded request will be destroyed.

The IIS supports to change this procedure:
https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configuring-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60#utf8servervars

Additionally to this, PHP has problems to handle utf-8 in filenames on windows. This Bug has been fixed with PHP 7.1:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33350

I solve the problem with changing the settings in IIS and upgrade to PHP 7.1.